# How to access phpMyAdmin on remote server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

For my websites I use Dreamhost.  Dreamhost requires you to create a hostname (ex: mysql.mclindigital.com) that the database will reside on.  For me it's simple, if I want to access phpMyAdmin, I simply navigate to [mysql.mclindigital.com](http://mysql.mclindigital.com), and it enters into phpMyAdmin automatically.

Apparently Dreamhost is in the minority using this method, because most people seem to use "localhost".  So, how do I access phpMyAdmin for these websites?  Will I need to get their Web Panel login info to browse around for this info?

As an example, I had a past client and I had to go here: http://216.120.237.104:2082/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php to get into their phpMyAdmin.  I never really understood what I was doing, but it just worked.  Now I am in the same situation, but this time the client isn't as tech-savvy and is unable to give me the URL I need to go to.

Also, I should point out I am not 100% certain that they have phpMyAdmin installed.  I do know they have a database however, because they are running a Wordpress Blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing magic or special about phpMyAdmin. It is just
a bunch of php scripts.

Some webhosts(Such as dreamhost) may install it as standard
similary to formmail and a bunch of other tools they may install.

Your problem is most likely that you client don't have
phpMyAdmin installed, and the easy solution(If you have ftp access)
is to go to http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php download
phpMyAdmin, configure it and then just upload it to their ftp server
your self. Then you can acces it similary to any other php script.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I didn't put 2 and 2 together.  Immediately the install seems confusing.  I've installed probably over 10 different PHP script packages, and I've never seen one as confusing.  The docs on the website seem to be vague as well.  I appreciate my WAMP setup that much more now :